# ASP.NET Worker Service making calls to Web API in a secure way

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web api written in ASP.NET Core.  I also have a Worker service performing work on a schedule.  Each time an iteration of work has been complete, I would like to notify users of an Angular application that consumes the web api as well.  I would like for the web api to use SignalR (whether it be Azure SignalR or self-hosted SignalR).  I'm thinking that the Worker service can make a call to the Web API with the meta data of the job that just completed as the payload.  Then the web api will broadcast to those listening.

The Angular app makes authenticated calls to the Web API with a trusted Active Directory B2C idToken and accessToken.  Since there is no user behind the Worker service, I'm not sure how to secure my web api to allow calls to a particular endpoint from my Worker service.  What type of authentication do I use for this endpoint?  What options do I have to choose from and where is the documentation for those approaches?

Comment: To the heroes voting to close this question: I've been struggling to find where to ask these types of questions.  If this type of question is truly not suitable for StackOverflow, at least spend a moment to contemplate suggesting where one might go to ask the question instead of here.  Closing the question with no feedback to the person asking the question often discourages the person asking the question to pursue the answer any further.  I've spent quite a while trying to figure this out myself.  I'm just trying to reach out to a smart community for help and direction.

Comment: this happens to me as well, when I have a tricky question and within minutes its closed. but I see the question is open as I write this.

Comment: Looking at your question, this seems like something that may be better served if it was deployed as a Azure Function. Perhaps you could rework your worker service into a Azure Function, and I believe Azure Function has a more convenient way to authenticate with .NET Core and SignalR or otherwise. I am no expert with worker services or azure function, but suggesting an idea.

Comment: For what it's worth, I voted to close this as too broad/tutorial request, because that's what it appears to be asking. High-level, conceptual questions without any code at hand yet are better suited for Software Engineering, not Stack Overflow. If you make a start with some implementation and run into problems, *then* SO is your site.

Comment: @TylerH, thanks for the feedback!  Is Software Engineering a StackExchange site?

Comment: @JakeSmith Yes. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What type of authentication do I use for this endpoint?

You need the **client_credentials** grant_type. Per the [OAuth2 docs](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/): *...The Client Credentials grant type is used by clients to obtain an access token outside of the context of a user...*

> What options do I have to choose from and where is the documentation for those approaches?

You mentioned that you are using AD B2C - in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#daemonsserver-side-applications), they mention that the Client Credentials flow is not currently supported.

However, there are [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) which specify how it can be setup by using Azure AD